# Getting gperftools to work with Rcpp

Tags: c++, r, rcpp, gperftools

I've read related posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13224322/profiling-rcpp-code-on-os-x) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23685206/is-my-using-gperftools-to-profile-a-r-script-with-rcpp-correct), and looked at Dirk Eddelbuettel's talk [here](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/papers/ismNov2009introHPCwithR.pdf) and yet I'm failing to even get a .log file from `gperftools`.  Here is my `R` file, called `Rcpp_practice.R`:

```
library(Rcpp)

Sys.setenv("PKG_LIBS"="-lprofiler")
sourceCpp('eigen.cpp')

a <- matrix(rnorm(300^2), 300, 300)
getEigenValues(a)
```

Here are the contents of `eigen.cpp`:

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
#include <gperftools/profiler.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::vec getEigenValues(arma::mat M) {
    return arma::eig_sym(M);
}
```

Then, on Terminal (I'm using OSX):

```
CPUPROFILE="eigenprof.log" R -f "Rcpp_practice.R"
```

I was hoping to see `eigenprof.log` sitting  in my working directory but I don't.  Also, I don't get the message that I've seen in other posts of the form `PROFILE: interrupts/evictions/bytes = 012/34/567891`

I verified that I have the latest version of `gperftools` installed. (`$ brew upgrade google-perftools` gives `Error: gperftools 2.5 already installed`).

What am I missing?

**Update**

After I modified my code to match @nrussell's I get this error message:

```
Error in dyn.load("/private/var/folders/6k/ffcchdq52kbb7d631b5vsqcw0000gn/T/RtmpCIdHkG/sourceCpp-x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-0.12.7/sourcecpp_6c3253d60384/sourceCpp_2.so") : 
unable to load shared object '/private/var/folders/6k/ffcchdq52kbb7d631b5vsqcw0000gn/T/RtmpCIdHkG/sourceCpp-x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-0.12.7/sourcecpp_6c3253d60384/sourceCpp_2.so':
dlopen(/private/var/folders/6k/ffcchdq52kbb7d631b5vsqcw0000gn/T/RtmpCIdHkG/sourceCpp-x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-0.12.7/sourcecpp_6c3253d60384/sourceCpp_2.so, 6): Symbol not found: _ProfilerStart
Referenced from: /private/var/folders/6k/ffcchdq52kbb7d631b5vsqcw0000gn/T/RtmpCIdHkG/sourceCpp-x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-0.12.7/sourcecpp_6c3253d60384/sourceCpp_2.so
Expected in: flat namespace
in /private/var/folders/6k/ffcchdq52kbb7d631b5vsqcw0000gn/T/RtmpCIdHkG/sourceCpp-x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-0.12.7/sourcecpp_6c3253d60384/sourceCpp_2.so
Calls: sourceCpp -> source -> withVisible -> eval -> eval -> dyn.load
Execution halted
```

This appears on the line with `sourceCpp` if I run the script interactively.

Comment: You are only showing partial commands.  This surely used to work many moons ago, and still should. What I would do is to retrace from a minimal `main()` in a c++ file, ensure I have all compilation and linking flags and options sorted out -- and then carry that to a Rcpp-based build.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have access to an OS X machine, but the following worked on Debian 8, where I've just added in the `ProfilerStart` / `ProfilerStop` calls to your C++ code (and not changed your R code at all¹):

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
#include <gperftools/profiler.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::vec getEigenValues(arma::mat M) {
    ProfilerStart("./eigen-prof.log");
    return arma::eig_sym(M);
    ProfilerStop();
}
```

¹*See update below.*

---

Then from a terminal,

```
R -f eigen-prof.R > /dev/null && google-pprof --text $(which R) eigen-prof.log 

# PROFILE: interrupts/evictions/bytes = 2/0/264
# Using local file /usr/local/bin/R.
# Using local file eigen-prof.log.
# /usr/bin/addr2line: /usr/local/bin/R: File format not recognized
# Total: 2 samples
#        1  50.0%  50.0%        1  50.0% dlamch_
#        1  50.0% 100.0%        1  50.0% dsymv_
#        0   0.0% 100.0%        1  50.0% 00000000004007ca
#        0   0.0% 100.0%        1  50.0% 00000000004007fa
#        0   0.0% 100.0%        1  50.0% 00007f84002bf0bd
#        0   0.0% 100.0%        1  50.0% 00007f84002bf2a8
#        0   0.0% 100.0%        1  50.0% 00007f84002c14c8
#        0   0.0% 100.0%        1  50.0% R_ReplConsole
#        0   0.0% 100.0%        1  50.0% Rf_ReplIteration
#        0   0.0% 100.0%        1  50.0% Rf_applyClosure
#        0   0.0% 100.0%        1  50.0% Rf_eval
#        0   0.0% 100.0%        1  50.0% __libc_start_main
#        0   0.0% 100.0%        1  50.0% dlatrd_
#        0   0.0% 100.0%        1  50.0% do_dotcall
#        0   0.0% 100.0%        1  50.0% dsyev_
#        0   0.0% 100.0%        1  50.0% dsytrd_
#        0   0.0% 100.0%        1  50.0% frame_dummy
#        0   0.0% 100.0%        1  50.0% run_Rmainloop
```

---

Regarding your updates, try changing the `sourceCpp` call to

```
sourceCpp(
    'eigen-prof.cpp',
    verbose = TRUE,
    rebuild = TRUE,
    cacheDir = "/tmp/profdir"
)
```

where I'm using `cacheDir = "/tmp/profdir"` to override the default random directory (`tempdir()`) that `sourceCpp` uses to build the shared library; and `rebuild = TRUE` to ensure that a new `.so` is generated each run.

Back in your shell, run these commands, substituting the appropriate file & directory names as needed:

- `R -f eigen-prof.R`
- `so_file=$(find /tmp/profdir/ -iname '*.so' -printf "%T+\t%p\n" | sort -r | head -n1 | awk '{print $2}')`
- `google-pprof --text $so_file eigen-prof.log`

This gives me

```
# Using local file /tmp/profdir/sourceCpp-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-0.12.7/sourcecpp_5dc5531d6f20/sourceCpp_4.so.
# Using local file eigen-prof.log.
# Total: 2 samples
#        1  50.0%  50.0%        1  50.0% dsterf_
#        1  50.0% 100.0%        1  50.0% dsymv_
#        0   0.0% 100.0%        2 100.0% 0x00000000004007ca
#        0   0.0% 100.0%        2 100.0% 0x00000000004007fa
#        0   0.0% 100.0%        2 100.0% R_ReplConsole
#        0   0.0% 100.0%        2 100.0% Rf_ReplIteration
#        0   0.0% 100.0%        2 100.0% Rf_applyClosure
#        0   0.0% 100.0%        2 100.0% Rf_eval
#        0   0.0% 100.0%        2 100.0% __libc_start_main
#        0   0.0% 100.0%        2 100.0% arma::auxlib::eig_sym
#        0   0.0% 100.0%        1  50.0% dlatrd_
#        0   0.0% 100.0%        2 100.0% do_dotcall
#        0   0.0% 100.0%        2 100.0% dsyev_
#        0   0.0% 100.0%        1  50.0% dsytrd_
#        0   0.0% 100.0%        2 100.0% eig_sym (inline)
#        0   0.0% 100.0%        2 100.0% getEigenValues
#        0   0.0% 100.0%        2 100.0% run_Rmainloop
#        0   0.0% 100.0%        2 100.0% sourceCpp_1_getEigenValues
#        0   0.0% 100.0%        2 100.0% syev (inline)
```

---

I threw the second step together on the fly so don't judge me on that; but it's just searching the directory you passed to `cacheDir` (`/tmp/profdir` in my case) for the most recently created (modified) `.so` file. You could also just grab the file name manually using Finder, etc. if your machine is lacking any of those programs.

Comment: *"Is this thing plugged in?"*

Comment: [_Get the machine that goes 'Biiing'_](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=arCITMfxvEc)

Comment: This at least gets me to a new error.  It's giant but starts `Error in dyn.load` and includes `unable to load shared object '/a/long/path/sourceCpp_2.so` and also `Expected in: flat namespace`.

Answer (score 3):

On OS X, I see the same error when naively trying to compile the code:

```
> Rcpp::sourceCpp('scratch/prof.cpp')
Error in dyn.load("/private/var/folders/tm/5dt8p5s50x58br1k6wpqnwx00000gn/T/RtmpgOwFk7/sourceCpp-x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-0.12.7.1/sourcecpp_9f424793a11/sourceCpp_2.so") : 
  unable to load shared object '/private/var/folders/tm/5dt8p5s50x58br1k6wpqnwx00000gn/T/RtmpgOwFk7/sourceCpp-x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-0.12.7.1/sourcecpp_9f424793a11/sourceCpp_2.so':
  dlopen(/private/var/folders/tm/5dt8p5s50x58br1k6wpqnwx00000gn/T/RtmpgOwFk7/sourceCpp-x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-0.12.7.1/sourcecpp_9f424793a11/sourceCpp_2.so, 6): Symbol not found: _ProfilerStart
  Referenced from: /private/var/folders/tm/5dt8p5s50x58br1k6wpqnwx00000gn/T/RtmpgOwFk7/sourceCpp-x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-0.12.7.1/sourcecpp_9f424793a11/sourceCpp_2.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /private/var/folders/tm/5dt8p5s50x58br1k6wpqnwx00000gn/T/RtmpgOwFk7/sourceCpp-x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-0.12.7.1/sourcecpp_9f424793a11/sourceCpp_2.so
```

The pertinent bit, `Symbol not found: _ProfilerStart`, implies that we aren't providing the compiler with the information needed to link to the Google perftools library. Adding a `-lprofiler` bit to the linker invocation is sufficient to fix this -- the simplest way is to add something to your `~/.R/Makevars` with something like:

```
LDFLAGS = -L/usr/local/lib -lprofiler
```

assuming you have Google perftools installed + symlinked to `/usr/local` in the standard way.

A more thorough solution would involve implementing the Rcpp attributes code necessary to generate these flags, so that adding `// [[Rcpp::plugin(gperftools)]]` would sufficient enough to ensure that Rcpp automagically added the flags needed. See `?Rcpp::Rcpp.plugin.maker` for some information on how that can be accomplished.